# Error: Updating Model from the database using Entity Framework

Tags: c#, mysql, entity-framework, asp.net-mvc-2, model

I have added a new table in the database which contains a column of type geometry. I am using VS10 with SP1. I updated my Entity framework to Microsoft Entity Framework June 2011 CTP as in earlier version geometry type column was not supported.
Now I am getting the following error "No EntityContainer exists in the model, so no code was generated" while auto-generation of MyDbContext.cs in MyProject.Data. 
What could be the problem ? Any help is much appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that you are using June 2011 CTP. The functionality has already shipped in form of EntityFramework 5 and Visual Studio 2012. Note that you need to unistall June CTP otherwise it will break your VS2012 installation. See this [blog post](http://blog.3d-logic.com/2012/04/11/entity-framework-zombie-a-k-a-microsoft-entity-framework-june-2011-ctp/) for more details

Comment: But I am using VS2010 not 2012

Comment: It is not supported in VS2010. This was only a CTP meaning it was not meant to be used in production and there is no support for this. In addition we have seen many weird issues caused by the binding redirect. Finally stuff will start breaking if you install .NET Framework 4.5 since you can start seeing MethodMissingExceptions and the likes. EF6 is supported on .NET Framework 4 (including spatial, enums etc.) but there is no designer that can handle this at the moment (and it is unlikely VS2010 will support it)